# Setting style by specific element vs by id

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have been working with a few examples have been wondering what the benefits (if any) there are of setting your style by one specific element or attaching an id to it and setting it via that? 
For example if we have this table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="cat1">
            <th scope='row'><span id='s'>Table Data</span></th>
            <td class='tdh'>Table Data</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr class="cat2">
            <th scope='row'><span id='s2'>Table Data</span></th>
            <td class='tdh'>Table Data</td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and wanted to style the span element we could grab the element by where it lies with the table:

```
table tr.cat1 span {
  some css;
}
```

or by the id:

```
#s {
  some css;
}
```

Are there any big differences in the way these actually work? I have found working with the id much simpler with a smaller margin for error, though I have found many examples of people using the former. Is there a specific reason for this? Or is it really just down to personal preference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO opinion you want to avoid styling by ID at all costs, but i also subscribe to the [OOCSS](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki) method of doing things that Nicole Sullivan has championed. Basically what it comes down to is that styles targeted by ID are not reusable, which usually starts to get out of hand and results in the exact same style declaration in multiple places, in addition to hijacking the specificity chain when they need to be overridden for certain cases. [This article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/) and [that wiki page](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki) describes it in a much better way than im willing to outline here.

Answer (score 1):

It's more of use the HTML attributes they way they are defined to be used.

ID's are meant to be unique identifiers for elements on a document/page.  So ID's usually are things like "main-navigation", "footer-wrapper", and "left-sidebar".

Classes are meant to be attributes to describe elements, they can also be used in combination.  Examples are This text is doubled spaced and grey and centered

Simply, use id's to identify and classes to describe and make the styles accordingly.

Comment: Good answer. IDs are OK for things that can logically only appear once. Classes are good for types of things that you expect to repeat, and want them all to be similar. When there are exceptions to the pattern, you annotate them with additional classes.